# Using Unity Ecs on Android Devices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use `JobComponentSystem` for players movement and rotation. In UnityEditor everything works fine. But when I try to build in my Android device `World.Active` returns null. After that in my first scene, I created a new `World` like:

```
World.Active = new World("DefaultWorld");
```

After that `World.Active` returns normal. But right now I am getting namespace not found error.

> Required UnityEngine and Unity.Entities.Hybrid types not found.

- Unity version => 2019.2.15f1
- Entities version => preview-0.1.1

Comment: Maybe try updating entities package to 0.3, 0.1 is quite outdated now (but 0.4 may throw errors in editor until its patched in few weeks)

Comment: Yeah but in my Unity version, entities 0.4 package is not available. In 2019.2.15f latest version of Entities is 0.1.1

Comment: Ok. Then you may want to specify what code throws what exception exactly

Comment: My problem is, I want to access EntityManager. But World.Active returns null. Anyway I fixed the problem. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, on mobile devices `World.Active` returns null. So you need to initialize entity World system. With this method you can initialize World system.

```
DefaultWorldInitialization.Initialize("TopShotz", isEditor);
```